# Import and export all except few exports from an npm package

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I am trying to export all exports from packageA and trying to create another packageB

**For example**

I am creating a new package (packageB) similar to Material UI. So to start with I have modified the `Switch` and `Grid` component of MUI.  But my packageB should have all imports from MUI except `Switch` and `Grid` which I customized.

This is what I tried but did not work.

```
import * as muiAllExports from '@mui/material';
const { Switch, Grid, ...rest} = muiAllExports;

export { rest };
```

Is there a way to do it?